# Viewing Japanese text correctly with MySQL Workbench from old database

Tags: text, cjk

Currently, in my MySQL database, if I do read the data, some fields having Japanese texts appears as garbage.

Changing fonts from preference is not working.

Any SQL command to view the data properly without altering DB?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we found the solution as follows:

SELECT CONVERT(CONVERT(CONVERT(table_column_name using latin1) using binary) using utf8) FROM database_name.table_name;